# CustomAction log name error 0x8007007a in WiX

Tags: windows, dll, installation, wix, naming-conventions

I am currently working on a custom action in a DLL that I export to be used by a WiX installer and I recently discovered the following error in the log when I ran the installer:

```
<exported_name_cut_off>: Error 0x8007007a: Failed to copy CustomAction log name: <exported_name_NOT_cut_off>
```

As I am relatively new to Windows programming and Wix, when I noticed the DLL function name was cut off in the error message I immediately thought there must be some limit of 31 characters on exported function names in DLLs, but that apparently is not the case; it turns out that this is a limitation of WiX of which I was unaware.

So, I have two questions here:

1. Is there a limit on the length of an exported or imported function name in DLLs? I could not find any mention of this in the MSDN help. If it is relevant, I am coding in C++ and using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 x64.
2. I found [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg29129.html), but unfortunately, there was no good answer given for why there is such a limit in WiX. Does anyone out there know why it is limited in this way? Is it still the case in WiX versions greater than 3.5.2519 (the version I am using)?

Comment: FYI The error code indicates buffer overflow problem, 0x8007007A `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Comment: Yes, I saw that when I looked up the error code in Visual Studio. This is something the WiX developers would have to fix, right?

Comment: I suppose it is something to be either documented or fixed, however right away since it's a buffer overflow then perhas something needs to be shortened for a workaround.

Comment: There's actually an open bug for this which I just found: http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/2542/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You control the name you pass to WcaInitialize; it doesn't have to be an actual function or custom action name so you can shorten it however you want. The WcaLog* functions use it to prefix your logging so it's not vital; you can even pass NULL if you want.

The limit still exists in WiX v3.6 and v3.7 beta builds.